# I want to make SMS AutoReply use J2ME programs

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I want to make SMS AutoReply use J2ME programs. I have method SendSMS(), I wish if I get a text message comes in, then the message before I set the SMS will be sent to the sender without having to click any button. How to activate the Reply button functionality without having to click the button?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it. Search the Example for **`APIBridege.jar`**

Using this .JAR file you can read the Messages from the Inbox, After reading a particular massage, can create an action to reply it back using Java ME Code.